# Invalid value used as weak map key in lodash memoize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lodash, formik

I am in the process of adding [Formik](https://formik.org/) to my React-Native project and have run into a problem where whenever I try to change form values, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key`.

It seems that the data that Formik is dispatching is correct, but it is throwing this error when executing the `setIn` function when updating form values which uses the lodash `toPath` method. This tries to turn the string ('salary', in my case) into a path by doing the following:

```
var stringToPath = memoizeCapped(function(string) {
  var result = [];
  if (string.charCodeAt(0) === 46 /* . */) {
    result.push('');
  }
  string.replace(rePropName, function(match, number, quote, subString) {
    result.push(quote ? subString.replace(reEscapeChar, '$1') : (number || match));
  });
  return result;
});
```

The problem is that while this method actually works and computes the correct output `['salary']`, it then gives me the above `TypeError` due to the `memoizeCapped` wrapper. If I remove the `memoizedCapped`, then everything works fine.

`memoizeCapped.js`:

```
function memoizeCapped(func) {
  var result = memoize(func, function(key) {
    if (cache.size === MAX_MEMOIZE_SIZE) {
      cache.clear();
    }
    return key;
  });

  var cache = result.cache;
  return result;
}
```

The resolver (second argument to `memoize`) in the above function will just return the first argument 'salary' when it is called inside `memoize`, which is causing the error as weak map keys must be objects.

The Formik library works on a fresh React-Native project, so there must be something we have changed that is causing this error but I am at a loss as to what it could be that is affecting the implementation of `lodash.memoize`. Also, if this is the case then `_stringToPath.js` should *always* give this error, so clearly I am missing something important.

I would very much appreciate some help if anyone has seen this sort of issue before?